# Create new custom tag from netui select tag

Tags: taglib, netui

For example, I have this code:

```
enter code here
<netui:select id="smt" dataSource="smt" >
<netui:selectOption value="1" title="one">red</netui:selectOption>
<netui:selectOption value="2" title="two">green</netui:selectOption>
<netui:selectOption value="3" title="three">blue</netui:selectOption>
</netui:select>
<div>This is my new custom tag</div>
```

How can I turn all this code above into one custom tag?